# why activerecord keeps sending the whole table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

This is my statement to retrieve data

```
@week_activities = Activity.where(:weeknum => 1)
```

This is how I am displaying it

```
<%= @week_activities.each do |d| %>
<%= d.id %>, <%= d.week %>, <%= d.day %> <br/>
<% end %>
```

It's displaying what I want they way I want it

```
1, 1, Monday 
2, 1, Tuesday 
3, 1, Wednesday 
4, 1, Thurday 
5, 1, Friday 
6, 1, Saturday 
7, 1, Sunday
```

Then for a reason I ignore, it displays the whole table as a array

```
[#<Activity id: 1, jog: 0, pushups: 0, situps: 0, bicycl: 0, squats: 0, 
 lunges: 0, foodid: 0, ccalor: 0, bcalor: 0, user_id: nil, 
 created_at: "2012-11-23 03:12:54", updated_at: "2012-11-23 03:12:54", week: 1, 
 day: "Monday"> ... and so on.
```

Is there any reason, it displaying the content of the whole table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using an `=` where you shouldn't.

```
<% @week_activities.each do |d| %>
```

Comment: I'm so upset at myself. Thank you very much

Comment: It's always the little things.  Cheers!